# Error: Conversion from 'objc_object*' to non-scalar type 'CGSize' requested. Please help?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following line is throwing the error, what's the matter with it?

> CGSize size = [label
>   sizeWithStyle:style
>   forWidth:bounds.size.width];

My code:

```
MSHook(void, drawRectLabel, SBIconLabel *self, SEL sel, CGRect rect)  {

CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

NSString *label(MSHookIvar<NSString *>(self, "_label"));

NSString *style = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"color: white; "];

CGSize size = [label sizeWithStyle:style forWidth:bounds.size.width];
[label drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((bounds.size.width - size.width) / 2, 0) withStyle:style];
```

}

Comment: What's the return type for sizeWithStyle:forWidth ?

Comment: `-sizeWithStyle:forWidth:` must be in a custom category, because it is not documented as part of the iOS SDK.  Without knowing what that method does, we can't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with -sizeWithStyle:forWidth:, but my guess is it returns an object, not a CGSize. Perhaps you could post the interface for that category method?